# Unable to run dynamically cross compiled application on arm device

Tags: android, c, arm, cross-compiling

I cross compiled an Hello application and try to run on ARM device without using `-static` argument, it does not work.

It shows the following error:

> /system/bin/sh: ./hello: No such file or directory

When I again compiled it using `-static` argument, it works fine.

I don't understand the reason for not working without `-static`.

Thanks

Comment: what is the size of executable with and without -static ?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. When you compile a c program without -static, linker will try to search for shared libraries but -static overrides this and linker goes to static library. The executable you get at the end is a standalone application because libraries it require to execute are a part of it now and that's why it works properly.

Comment: i agree to your point that when i compile using -static, all libraries are part of the executable.. I tried with a very simple hello, no external libraries. there is enough difference in the size, without static-12bytes and with static 860bytes.

Comment: which arm device you are using ?

Comment: i am using android device using arm a7.

Comment: Could you post the code and the command that you use to compile it? What is used SDK?

Comment: I am not using any SDK. Code:                                                                                                        #include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int i;
        printf("Hello World\n");
}                                                                                                                Command: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello -o hello.c

Comment: Did you installed a complete toolchain? libc cross, etc..

Comment: I  install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi for cross compilation. What other things required for the its cross compilation ?                                                  i have already installed the below tools: $ sudo apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross
$ sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev

Comment: Compile command have to be: `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello`

Comment: Sorry, that was typo error. I compiled using "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello" command only.

Comment: In short, if you link against copies of some Linux libraries bundled with a cross-toolchain, it shouldn't be too big a surprise that those same libraries might not be installed on a device _not running Linux_.

Comment: @Notlikethat Well, it is correct. But OP is compiling using libc only. If the toolchain is correctly installed, what can be wrong compiling a very simple program?

Comment: @LPs Android doesn't have the appropriate version of glibc, largely because it doesn't have glibc at all; Android has a different file system hierarchy and thus the expected library search paths are elsewhere. Primarily, though, Android doesn't use the Linux dynamic loader, so you fall at the very first hurdle - hence why it's an obvious duplicate of a Q&A explaining exactly that.

Comment: @Notlikethat I'm such a moron, I didn't see the Android tag. :)

Comment: Thanku so much for your explanation.:) Can we have any solution to run the application without "-static". Actually my purpose is to run glmark2 executable not .apk on Android device, there is no support for its static compilation or dependencies issues.

Comment: As suggested by @Notlikethat linked SO answer: _You should use NDK or another Android-targeted toolchain when compiling programs for Android_